# How to set window title with a colored string in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtgui, qpainter

How to set window title with a colored string in Qt? And how to set window title with a partly colored string in Qt? For example

```
My Office [red]

My Office [black] - my.doc [red]
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of another application doing what you want? (Doesn't need to be a Qt application, any will do)

Comment: You need to create custom window, based on widget with Qt::FramelessWindowHint flag. Because native windows (on win/*nix/mac) does not support native colored headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to set window title with a colored string in Qt? And how to set
>   window title with a partly colored string in Qt?

You cannot control that from Qt as it is not Qt drawing them in the end. However, you can use `QPainter` with the following methods to draw a custom title bar line on top of your widget:

```
void QPainter::setPen(const QColor & color)

void QPainter::setBrush(const QBrush & brush)

void QPainter::drawLine(const QLine & line)
```

You could check out the [analog clock example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html) in Qt for painting customization.

Do not forget about the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag either.